# How to consult the number of connections from specifics clients or ips in my secondary nodes

Tags: replication, mongodb, monitoring, connections

I need to know how to consult the number of connections from specifics clients or ips in my secondary nodes, I have a replica set composed of 3 nodes (one primary node and two secondary nodes), the development colleagues need to consult the databases but it is necessary guarantee that certain reads are performed on secondary nodes only (Read Preference:secondary), how can I know if connections from development users are reaching my secondary nodes? I would need to show the IP or some element that indicates that the origin of the connection is from the development colleagues,
Greetings!